# Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_REPL_INPUT]: Listeners for `uncaughtException` cannot be used in the REPL at Object.compile

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am new to truffle and I work on blockchain project so when I "migrate" in truffle develop, this error occurs. Why ? I change the version of my compiler by 4.25 in truffle-config.js but nothing has changed. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This could help:

```
truffle migrate --reset
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
npm un -g truffle
npm i -g truffle@nodeLTS
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error. I tried the other fixes posted, and Javi's did work for me. All I had to do was downgrade to node v10 from v12.

You can use n to do this:

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo n 10.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using node v12?

If you are using v12 then try to use v10.

You can install NVM and use node v10 in this project.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
truffle develop
```

and then

```
migrate --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, and the basic solution I found out is to change the truffle version to the current version.

```
npm install -g truffle

which will install the current version of truffle

Truffle v5.5.9 (core: 5.5.9)

Ganache v^7.0.3

Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)

Node v14.17.6

Web3.js v1.5.3

previously I was using this which gave me the error,

Truffle v5.0.2 (core: 5.0.2)

Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)

Node v14.17.6
```